# how to implement an integration rule ?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I've checked the identity below, how to implement it in Mathematica ?

```
(* {\[Alpha] \[Element] Reals, \[Beta] \[Element] Reals, \[Mu] \[Element] Reals, \[Sigma] > 0} *)

Integrate[CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], \[Alpha] + \[Beta] x] PDF[
NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] -> CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (\[Alpha] + 
\[Beta] \[Mu])/Sqrt[1 + \[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]^2]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most ways to do what you request would probably involve adding rules to built-in functions (such as `Integrate`, `CDF`, `PDF`, etc), which may not be a good option. Here is a slightly softer way, using the `Block` trick - based macro:

```
ClearAll[withIntegrationRule];
SetAttributes[withIntegrationRule, HoldAll];
withIntegrationRule[code_] :=
   Block[{CDF, PDF, Integrate, NormalDistribution},
      Integrate[
        CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], \[Alpha]_ + \[Beta]_ x_] PDF[
           NormalDistribution[\[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_], x_], {x_, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] :=
                CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (\[Alpha] + \[Beta] \[Mu])/
                   Sqrt[1 + \[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]^2]];
      code];
```

Here is how we can use it:

```
In[27]:= 
withIntegrationRule[a=Integrate[CDF[NormalDistribution[0,1],\[Alpha]+\[Beta] x]
    PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]],x],{x,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]];
a

Out[28]= 1/2 Erfc[-((\[Alpha]+\[Beta] \[Mu])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1+\[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]^2]))]
```

When our rule does not match, it will still work, automatically switching to the normal evaluation route:

```
In[36]:= 
  Block[{$Assumptions = \[Alpha]>0&&\[Beta]==0&&\[Mu]>0&&\[Sigma]>0},
    withIntegrationRule[b=Integrate[CDF[NormalDistribution[0,1],\[Alpha]+\[Beta] x]
        PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]],x],{x,0,\[Infinity]}]]]

Out[36]= 1/4 (1+Erf[\[Alpha]/Sqrt[2]]) (1+Erf[\[Mu]/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])])
```

where I set `\[Alpha]` to `0` in assumptions to make the integration possible in a closed form.

Another alternative may be to implement your own special-purpose integrator.

Comment: How can one release HoldAll such that it will work for the integral, say, of `(CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], \[Alpha] + \[Beta] x] + CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], \[Gamma] + \[Delta] x]) PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x]` ? I tried `Distribute` but it didin't work.

Comment: @b.gatessucks This is not a problem of `HoldAll`. If I release that, the integral inside our macro will evaluate via its normal route before the macro sees it, which is what we don't want. Inside `Block`, however, all `Blocked` functions completely forget what they are. So, within this solution, the only choice is to add another rule to `Integrate`, such as `Integarte[x_+y_,varlims_]:=Integrate[x,varlims]+Integrate[y,varlims]`. Eventually, though, you'd end up re-implementing the whole `Integrate`, so it may make sense to constrain what you want to get from this, from the start.

Comment: This may sound like a hostile question but really it is just ignorance on my part:  Now that we are a decade of Mathematica releases since this question came up, and since Mathematica's vision is to incorporate mathematical knowledge in such a manner as to compute that which can reasonably be automated, and Moore's law has continued to exponentiate computational resources, why has it remained so seemly "dumb" regarding utilization of known identities? https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.01344

Comment: @user3673 That's a very valid question IMO, but alas I can't answer that.